# How to properly call an external class method from an anoymous function

Tags: javascript, class, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an event listener to buttons, using a for loop
Inside the loop I declared an anonymous function. the basic test (alert) is working
But when I try to call an external class method, it won't work

The class works outside of this loop
The alert and entire code are working fine (there's not runtime error)

What am I missing ?

```
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    (function() {
        var j = i;
        buttons[j].addEventListener(
            'click',
            function() {
                alert('hello world ' + j);
                classname0.method(buttons[j].id);
            },
            false,
        );
    })();
}
```

Comment: Note, its better to use console.log to debug instead alert

Comment: Can you share the code of the class you are referring to?

Comment: `class` is a reserved name in javascript (even when not used). Also is your `class` available in the scope you are ruinning the loop or calling the function?

Comment: I tried to anonymize the real class name, I'll fix it

Comment: so when you say, 'class works outside of this loop', what it does? and when it doesn't work, means what's not working.

Comment: the method goes over the dom and updates it. also works without anonymous function, and inside a promise inside a loop...

Comment: I don't see a reason for the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) this is usually done to create a new scope in a for loop with asynchronous or event handling code but you don't need to create the scope because the [let statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) solves this (I'm a bigger fan of using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead though).

Comment: Ok, how do you suggest I'll handle it then ? what's the proper syntax ?

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information to have any idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You write your function this way

```
(function(){ ... }() )
```

instead of

```
(function(){ ... })()
```

Comment: it's because it is now executed while it wasn't before, they might be others errors. As Nikos M. said, class is a reserved keyword. Give us more information. Please show your definition for classname0.

Comment: @SylvanLEDEUNFF What are you talking about, both ways of writing the IIFE are completely the same.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I've never seen this one in any official documentation like https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Glossaire/IIFE

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need "call" to get the correct "this" on your class.

```
classname0.method.call(classname0, buttons[j].id);
```